# Fragments and multiple listviews

Tags: android, listview, navigation, fragment

Currently I am trying to implement a ListFragment or ListView navigation system where a user clicks on an item in the listview which then transitions and replaces it with another listview.

So Container Activity A has a screen. You press a button and it replaces that container with a ListView. You then choose one of the items and it then replaces the screen with a new fragment Listview. This repeats until a user gets to the end of the line to the product itself.

The Amazon APP currently has this implemented for their Item Navigation.

I am just looking for ideas on how to start a design pattern to create an app like amazon.

Does anyone know how they execute this? I am having problems finding the correct key word search to find examples of this functionality. If anyone can help me lead to examples to mimic this design it would be helpful!

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: 2Dee you don't need to be an ass =( I am new here. You can be helpful like the user below or you can just move on with another question. There's no need to flag it...

On top of that I didn't violate anything on that page, if I did, explain how I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly you want to do but if you want to replace a listview with another listview on click of an item in listview, then you dont have to make it so complicated.

Have a listview in which you feed data from an array using an adapter. On list item click. Change the data array with new array in the adapter and notify the listview.

Something like this:

```
mListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mylist);
mAdapter = new Adapter(this, mArray1);
mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
                        int position, long id) {

-----

mAdapter.setListData(mArray2);
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This way it will work for you.

Comment: The reason I don't want to do that is because that would start up a new activity and replace the whole screen correct?

I want to keep my current header action bar and only replace a section of a screen. That would require using a fragment container and fragment transactions to replace the view.

My google searches for examples hasn't netted me any answers yet. 

This example below is what I am looking for but I wanted to do it with fragments
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-multilevel-listview-tutorial/

Comment: It will just update your listview with new data. It wont start new activity!! The method I stated above is for changing the dataset of listview.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Sushil!! But there seems to be no method of the type

setListData()

What other methods are there to update a list?

Comment: Hi Sushil, after coding for the last few weeks, I have picked up a few things here and there and came back to check on your solution! It all makes sense to me now and your solution was perfect and works, but I didn't understand it at the time. 

I just wanted to say thank you for responding to my question! I just don't have a need for this navigation style anymore.

Again, thanks!
Quan